# Python Multiprocessing - Merge Sort solution

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a mergesort with Python multiprocessing without any built-in functions so that each level of the sort gets launched in a new process. After the sublists reaching a certain threshold, the algorithm should switch to bubblesort (I know it's not the best, but I'm just excercising). I have two issues, first issue is, I can't really wrap my head around where the merging part should occur. If I merge all the sorted sublists back in the main function, it works OK, but that's not how it should work. So now I'm trying to keep my `manager.list()` merged, but I've run into an error, where even though I explicitly state that there should be no operations if the length of the list is smaller than 2 via a loop like this:

```
while (len(resp) > 1):
    resp.append(merge(resp.pop(0), resp.pop(0)))
```

some of the processes still come back with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-66-193b11c211db>", line 34, in merge_sort
    resp.append(merge(resp.pop(0), resp.pop(0)))
  File "<string>", line 2, in pop
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 774, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

So my main question is, how should I implement this algorithm? Or, to be more precise, where and how should the merging occur? The code is a bit too big for an SO question, so you can find it [here](https://codeshare.io/5ejgAa). Oh and I've also seen [this](https://devopslog.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/mergesort-example-using-python-multiprocessing/) solution, but this one just cuts the input data into chunks and processes those chunks separately, however, I'd have to create a new process for each level of splitting, not for a chunk of data.

Comment: I think your double pop doesn't work because your check + pop is not atomic, when you check resp could be len=3 but before the process that did the check makes it to the pop instructions some other process already pop-ed twice and now you end up with len=1 and two pops to do...

Comment: That was my guess also... Any idea how to do this without that popping?

Comment: you will probably have to use some kind of locking mechanism I'm afraid, don't think there is any built-in give-me-two-if-posssible sadly.